# Physics, Engineering, Space Exploration or Aviation

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question on an alternative way to achieve orbit, but I am getting advised to ask at different sites.

How can I ask the questions below as one question on all applicable sites?

- https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/18090/electric-diagonal-rail-for-rockets
- [Electric diagonal rail for rockets/space shuttle using a modified E-fan](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/278646/electric-diagonal-rail-for-rockets-more-physics-than-not)

I know I have some revising of the question to do, but I want to address the out of scope issue first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the problem is that the question that you have asked on those two sites is quite broad and poorly tailored to each.

Consequently, I think only parts of it may be on-topic for any individual site, and you need to break it up into more focussed questions to ask on the site appropriate to each.

I would advise working with the sites on which you have already posted your question, by taking on board their requests for clarification and scope reduction within your question, and editing your question on each site until part of it becomes on-topic and answerable there.